# Enviar formulário "serializado" mais variável via AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html5

Quero serializar meu formulário, e enviar outra variáveis.
É possível?

Exemplo:

```
var id = "1";

function register(){
  $.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: "meu_script.php",
    data: $("#form").serialize(), //Aqui eu queria passar a variável *id*
  });
}
```

Comment: Uma opção poderia ser colocar um input type hidden, mas quero passar essa variável via AJAX mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
var ID = 100;
function register() {
    var data = $('#form').serializeArray();
    data.push({name: "id", value: ID});
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'meu_script.php',
        data: $.param(data),
    });
}
```

Usando o [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) para serializar o formulário e adicionar mais valores

Comment: Boaaa!
Não tinha pensado nisso.
Valeuu!